# How to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis via JMX via ssl?

Tags: java, jmx, activemq-artemis

I have code where I connect to a broker using the JMX protocol but without SSL. I made the broker settings so that it works via SSL, but how can I attach a certificate in an application that uses JMX?

Configuration from `broker.xml`:

```xml
<acceptor name="main-connector">tcp://localhost:61617?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=keystore_server.jks;trustStorePath=truststore_server.jks;keyStorePassword=qwerty;trustStorePassword=qwerty;needClientAuth=true;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;enabledCipherSuites=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA;enabledProtocols=TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2</acceptor>
```

The structure of my broker folder:

[image]

My code for connecting via JMX:

```java
public static MBeanServerConnection connectBroker(String brokerUrl, String login, String password) {
    MBeanServerConnection mBeanServerConnection = null;
    try {
        Map<String, String[]> env = new HashMap();
        String[] creds = {login, password};
        env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
        JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + brokerUrl + "/jmxrmi"), env);
        mBeanServerConnection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
        DialogsAlert.brokerJmxRmiConnectionSuccess.showAndWait();
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"success" + brokerUrl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING,"fail", e);
    }
    return mBeanServerConnection;
}
```

I don't really understand how to enclose my keystore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem with your broker configuration is that JMX connectivity is **not** configured in `broker.xml`. It is configured in `management.xml` as described in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#remote-jmx-access). Keep in mind that JMX and JMS connections are completely different. JMS is for *messaging* and JMX is for *management*.

SSL parameters can be configured on the JMX client application using these system properties:

- `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`
- `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType`
- `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`
- `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`
- `javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType`
- `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`

More details are available in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/management/monitoring-and-management-using-jmx-technology.html#GUID-FA9A0A97-6016-4283-9E9C-983C4D6F96D4).

Comment: The JMX settings are configured in broker.xml and management.xml. If you need to use system properties, can I change them at runtime? Let's say it will be a graphical application that will dynamically change the parameters on the button. Will they be able to change at runtime? And how can I finally connect to the broker via ssl?

Comment: What JMX connectivity settings are in `broker.xml`?

Comment: You can change system properties at runtime. Simply use [`System.setProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)).

Comment: jmx settings in broker.xml: <jmx-management-enabled>true</jmx-management-enabled>
In Map env should I put these values? env.put("jmx.remote.x.password.file", System.getProperty("password.file","<default_path>"));

Comment: The `jmx-management-enabled` is just a general switch to enable JMX management on the broker. It doesn't control anything related to _connectivity_. The `jmx.remote.x.password.file` property is for configuration of the MBean _server_, not the client.

Comment: Everything worked out, thank you very much